# How to properly use the dispose method on a class

Tags: c#, windowsformshost

I'm working on a database and I need to write the database to file when the database class is destroyed along with every else when the form is closed

This is how I'm currently calling it:

```
class database: IDisposable
{
    List<databaseEntry> dDatabase;

    public database()
    {
        dDatabase = new List<databaseEntry>;
    }
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
             StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path);

             string toWrite;

             foreach (databaseEntry dE in dDatabase)
             {
             toWrite = dE.rfid.ToString() + " " + dE.currentArea.ToString() + " " + dE.itemName;
             sw.WriteLine(toWrite);
             }

             sw.Close();
             disposed = true;
         }
     }//destructor for database (saves database to file)

     public void Dispose()
     {
          Dispose(true);
          GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
     }
 }
```

The Dispose method isn't called when I close the windows form that this class is open in.

This is for an assignment and I'm not allowed to use SQL for this.

Comment: "and I need to write the database to file when the database class is destroyed." - that seems a poor design.

Comment: Well you aren't "using" your `StreamWriter` as you would normally use a disposable class, I'm guessing you're not "using" your `database` class either yes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not have control over when the `Dispose` method is called by the garbage collector. If you want to dispose resources when the form is closed, you should manually call the `Dispose` method when the form is closed.

This is achieved by listening to the [FormClosed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of the form.

So you would do something similar to this:

1. Create this method:

   ```
   private void Form1_FormClosed(Object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
   {
       if(this.database != null)
           this.database.Dispose(); 
   }
   ```
2. Put this line in your form's constructor:

   ```
   this.FormClosed += Form1_FormClosed;
   ```

Since you're implementing `IDisposable`, another solution would be to wrap your database object instantiation in a `using` statement - this would automatically call `Dispose` once the code in the `using` statement completes.

Syntax for your use case is as follows:

```
using(database db = new database())
{
    //use your db object
} //db is disposed here
```

Comment: you posted your answer while I was typing mine.  I'm going to leave mine since I gave a bit more on the GC, but you get an up vote from me.

Comment: Thank you kind sir, +1 to you too.

Comment: I didn't actually know that there was a listener for formClosed. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Edit:

Matthew Watson’s comment made me realize my answer is over simplified and could be confusing (thanks for the comment Matthew).  Here’s (most of) the real story:

All objects have a constructor and a destructor.  If these are not specified the default constructor and destructor are used.

Constructor:

```
ClassName()
```

Destructor:

```
~ClassName()
```

The Constructor is called when you use the new keyword.  The Destructor *can be called* once there is no longer a reference to that specific instance of an object.  Notice I said *can be called*, not *is called*.  Meaning at this point the object is eligible for garbage collection and could be freed when the garage collector runs.  I will not go into detail here but just know that the garage collector does not always collect all the unreachable objects for performance reasons.  This is one of the key reasons you would want to the `IDisposable` interface.  You can immediately clean up resources when you know they are no longer being used vs. waiting for the GC to clean up the resources.  When working with streams or database connections it is a good idea to implement the `IDisposable` interface.

With that said here is the updated answer (replacing the previous "default Dispose()" references with the destructor reference).

Since this is an assignment I am not going to give you the answer per se, but I'll get you close.  The destructor (~database) is normally called by the garage collector when an instance of a `database` object is no longer reachable.  By implementing the `IDisposable` interface you have provided an alternative to allowing the garage collector to dispose of the object.  You are telling the garage collector "I know when and how these resources need to be freed" vs. free these resources when there are no longer references to the objects.  But that only applies if you call your Dispose method; more specifically the line:

```
Dispose(true);
GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
```

This means "Garage collector, do not call the destructor (~database()) method, I have already handled it".

What you should do in this method is close any streams (StreamWriter) you have open.

Usage:  The `IDisposable` interface has a nice construct in C# the `using` statement.  This is in effect a `try catch` block where the Dispose method is called in the `finally` block.  StreamWriter also implements IDisposable so you should think about implementing the `using` statement in your `database` class.  Example:

```
using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter()){
    //do stuff with writer here
}
```

This is the pattern you should use for your database class in your form.  I will let you figure out how to code that up.

Comment: Dispose() is *not* called by the garbage collector. The *finalizer* is called by the garbage collector, and the implementation of the finalizer in the C# class may or may not call Dispose(). (Note that the finalizer is also called a destructor in C#.)

Comment: Matthew, you are right.  I was trying to over simplify for an example for a student.  I will update my answer to clarify this.

Comment: Arrrg. Im freaking out. Its garbage not garage!! Anyway thanks for your detailled response :)